# gnuplot filledcurves not fully filled

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to fill the area between the curve and the axis with the following command in gnuplot:

```
plot 1/x w filledcurves above x1=0 t "", x t "y=x"
```

However the area between the curve and x axis is not fully filled(I'm not able to post an image). I did some research but find nothing. Any one can help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fill the area between the curve and the x-axis you must use `above y1=0`. This is a bit counter intuitive and also took me a while to find out.

```
plot 1/x w filledcurves above y1=0 t "", x t "y=x"
```

`above x1` means above the x1-axis (i.e. the lower horizontal plot border), and `above x1=0` means above a *vertical* line with the value `x=0`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The area between x axis and the curve is fully filled but I notice that the area between y axis and the curve is not. Any idea how to sovle this? Thanks.

Comment: @JiakaiXiao Standard sampling is 100. If you have a range [0:10] the data points have spacing of about 0.1. So, the first datapoint which is not `1/0` or `NaN` is around 0.1 (your "gap"). If you want to get closer to zero increase sampling, i.e. add a line `set samples 500` or a higher number.